# How to include lwIP original source code into my project?

Tags: gcc, arm, atmel, lwip

I am currently implementing a simple tcp/ip server using an Atmel AT91SAM9260 evaluation board (ARM based micro-controller with several peripherals).

Some examples, given by Atmel include a uIP based web server but uIP cannot handle the throughput needed.

I found the same example based on version 1.1.1 (or slightly above) that was serving me just enough.

Recently I began to have problems with the stack and I couldn't find a port to the AT91SAM9260 with a newer version of lwIP. To build the project, I am using Eclipse+Yagarto+gcc as a development stack.

After just replacing the source code of the latest version 1.4.0 (available at http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/lwip/) into my project and attempting to fix all compile errors, I gave up.

The structure of the source code is very similar but apparently there's too many tweaks to be made.

Is there a specific guide on adapting the original source code to my stack? Wasn't the C++ code supposed to just compile on my stack?

Answer (score 2):

At the wiki of LwIP http://lwip.wikia.com/wiki/Projects_that_use_lwIP I do see a reference to contributed ports of LwIP 1.3.0. That may be a starting point, at least for the ethernetif.c file.

To try and answer the second question: The C (not C++) is supposed to compile, but one still has to (at least):

- setup lwipopts.h to determine how LwIP is to be used
- provide ethernetif.h/ethernetif.c to tie your hardware to LwIP
- setup sys_arch.h/sys_arch.c